# Listar dados em uma tabela usando ajax php e bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, bootstrap-3

Estou enfrentando uma serie de problemas e duvidas com ajax! Tenha a seguinte função que atualiza os dados e lista em uma tabela:

```
 function atualiza(){
                $.ajax({    
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: 'get_enderecos.php',
                    success: function(data){
                        for(var i=0; data.length>i;i++){
                            $('#enderecos').append('<tr><td>'+data[i].sequencia+'</td><td>'
                                                    +data[i].cep+'</td><td>'+data[i].endereco+
                                                    '</td><td>'+data[i].bairro+'</td><td>'+data[i].cidade+
                                                    '</td><td>'+data[i].estado+
                                                    '</td><td class="actions col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" align="center">'+
                                                        <button class="btn btn-danger" id="teste" type="button">Alterar Endereço</button>);
                            }
                        }
                    });
            }
```

PHP:

```
<?php

    require_once('acessabanco.php');
    
    $objDb = new db();
    $link = $objDb->conecta_banco(); 

    $sql = " SELECT sequencia, cep, endereco, bairro, cidade, estado FROM ENDERECOS";

    $lista = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

        while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($lista)){
            $vetor[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $resultado);
        }
        echo json_encode($vetor);
        
?>
```

HTML:

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-responsive"> 
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th> Código </th>
                                <th> CEP </th>
                                <th> Endereço </th>
                                <th> Bairro </th>
                                <th> Cidade </th>
                                <th> Estado </th>
                                <th> Alterar </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                         <tbody id="enderecos">
                        </tobody> 
                    </table>
```

**Eu acho que essa não é a melhor maneira (parece gambiarra) pra listar os dados em uma tabela, por exemplo: o botão que coloquei, nao consigo acessar ele, talvez pelo fato dele estar sendo declarado justamente em uma função JS. Existe a maneira correta de se fazer esse procedimento?**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: O resultado, quando aperto em cima do botao para me exibir um simples ALERT(), ele nao exibe nada, porem nao exibe nenhum erro.]

Comment: O botão é fora do javascript, primeira mudança

Comment: Mas como eu coloco ele fora? Se quando eu coloco ele me gera o seguinte erro: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

OBS: '<button>...</button>' para <button>...<button>

Comment: faltou a aspas simples '<button class="btn btn-danger" id="teste" type="button">Alterar Endereço</button>'  faz assim

Comment: Ele da certo dessa forma que voce falou, alias era como estava.
Porem, eu nao consigo encontrar ele quando faço a seguinte chamada:

 $('#teste').on('click',teste); que executa a seguinte funcao: 
 function teste(){
                alert(data.cep);
            }

Comment: parece que faltou fechar tipo depois do `</button>' + '</td></tr>';`

Comment: '<button class="btn btn-danger" onClick="teste();" type="button">Alterar Endereço</button>'+
'</td></tr>'

Mesmo problema.

Comment: é mais faltava isso, outra coisa se tem como colocar a imagem disso?

Comment: Já posto, perai

Comment: A imagem do resultado da pagina

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta, da uma olhada... Não aguento mais olhar pra isso e nao conseguir resolver! rs

Comment: Postado! De uma olhada ai..

Comment: Esse `data.length` não faz sentido.. Posta na pergunta o que retorna esse `data`...  essa é a chave da questão, por isso seu loop `for`não funciona

Comment: O botão alterar endereço que é o probleama?

Comment: Um `data.length`só faria sentido se retornasse uma array, como retorna um JSON, não faz sentido algum.

Comment: Tem que ver a estrutura desse JSON para poder fazer um loop.

Comment: o meu LOOP está funcionando corretamente, agora que voce disse eu vi que nao faz muito sentido, mas o problema nao está no for, e sim na requisicao que eu tento fazer quando aperto no botao ALTERAR ENDEREÇO. Teoricamente ele teria que me exibir um simples alert: 

 '<button class="btn btn-danger" **id="teste1"** type="button">Alterar Endereço</button>'

 $('#teste1').on('click',teste);

   function teste(){
                alert('a');
            }

Comment: sim, no botao alterar.

Comment: Coloca `$('#teste1').on('click',teste);` dentro do `success` do Ajax, no final

Comment: Consegui resolver meu amigo, muito obrigado pela ajuda!!!!!!! Sempre grato a voces!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui Resolver o problema, colocando a function fora da funcão que verifica se o documento está pronto!

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready( function(){
)};

function teste(){
                alert('a');
            }
</script>
```

E chamando ele pelo onClick="" no botao!

```
 '<button class="btn btn-danger" onClick="teste()" type="button">Alterar Endereço</button>'
```

Agradeço a todos pela ajuda! E por perder um pouco do seu tempo tentando me ajudar.

**MUITO OBRIGADO!**